# Problem with display data from get_option

Tags: plugin-development, options, notices

I have a problem with get_option function. I created options page with one field for testing in form. Everything saving data to database, but when i try display it i getting "Undefined index", but this index exists in the get_option array:

```
Array
(
    ['turn_on'] => 1
)
```

When i trying:

```
print_r($variable);
```

i getting something like up, but when i trying:

```
print_r($variable['turn_on']);
```

i getting Undefined index, do someone know why this working like that and how can i fix it?

// Edit

Class

```
if (!class_exists('GoToTopOrBottom')) {
    class GoToTopOrBottom {
        private $options;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->parent_slug = 'wtyczki';
            $this->slug = 'go-to-top-or-bottom';

            add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'addSubpage']);
            add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'registerFields']);
        }

        public function addSubpage ()
        {
            add_submenu_page(
                $this->parent_slug,
                'Przejście w górę lub dół',
                'Góra lub dół',
                'manage_options',
                $this->slug,
                [
                    $this,
                    'view'
                ]
            );
        }

        public function view()
        {
            require_once(plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . '/views/go-to-top-or-bottom/go-to-top-or-bottom.php');
        }

        public function registerFields()
        {
            register_setting(
                'go_to_top_or_bottom_group',
                'go_to_top_or_bottom'
            );

            add_settings_field(
                'turn_on',
                null,
                null,
                $this->slug
            );
        }
    }

    if (is_admin()) {
        new GoToTopOrBottom;
    }
}
```

And View Form on Admin Option Page

```
<div class="mt-3">
    <h3>Powrót do góry lub dołu strony</h3>
    <HR />
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
        $this->options = get_option('go_to_top_or_bottom');
            settings_fields('go_to_top_or_bottom_group');
        ?>
        <pre>
            <?php
             print_r($this->options['turn_on']);
            ?>
        </pre>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="go_to_top_or_bottom['turn_on']" value="1">
                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                <span class="custom-control-description">Włączyć plugin?</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                        test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class-"col-4">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz zmiany</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try `$option = get_option( 'turn_on' );`

Comment: Can you update your code with the full context. Including your use of `get_option()`.

Comment: I updated main post, @Drupalizeme this not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inserting the value of the `get_option('go_to_top_or_bottom');`as a property in the `$this->options` so when you actual try to print it like this `print_r($this->options['turn_on']);`you get the index error because this is a property!!!

Correct way will be `$this->options['turn_on']=get_option('go_to_top_or_bottom');`

### Update

I see that the `$options` is a private meaning you cannot access it outside of the class.

A solution will change the type to `public` Or introduce another property as `public`.

If you don't want to change the `Class` you can create a variable to use it in the view file like this :

`$options=get_option('go_to_top_or_bottom');`

And access them with `$options["'turn_on'"];`
Mind the single quotes ( This is due to the serialization with the quoted names).

Comment: Ok so what now:

`Array
(
    ['turn_on'] => 1
    ['anything'] => 1
)`

Comment: Your questions were about the undefined index. So this is answered. What do you think is missing?

Comment: In the database it look like [https://i.imgur.com/aeIVaKx.png](https://i.imgur.com/aeIVaKx.png), i need display turn_on or anything, with your solution i can't do this. Just can only display array with all options inserted in go_to_top_or_bottom option name. `Array
(
    [go_to_top] => Array
        (
            ['turn_on'] => 1
            ['anything'] => 1
        )

)` So when i now try $this->options['go_to_top'] it show me array, but when i try check value for turn_on or anything, i getting undefined index. PS. I did it with WordPress Codex.

Comment: The Database has the serialize values. For example `$option_turn_on['turn_on']` will have the value of 1.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and what the expected behavior will be to better understand and help you?

Comment: I have a plugin where i created one field go_to_top_or_bottom in the wp_options table, in value i will save all options from this plugin admin page. When i get_option for go_to_top_or_bottom option name from wp_options i getting value like an array with turn_on, anything etc. Now when i get this option i wanna use what value is saved for turn_on or anything, when i trying do this, i getting error Undefined Index. Now = $options = get_option('go_to_top_or_bottom'); - here i have array with turn_on and anything, when i try $options['turn_on'] i getting Undefined Index, same for anything.

Comment: You need `$options['go_to_top']['turn_on']` :)

Comment: This not working, still Undefined Index, i tried it, i tried everything what came to my head, but i didn't find solution for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69163/discussion-between-drupalizeme-and-adrian).